# Python doesn't output a print statement to the console window

Tags: python, console, ide, spyder

I'm using Spyder as an IDE, Python version is 3.7 (Anaconda).  I'm brand new in Python but have done many other languages. This was working earlier, but now I can't make the simplest print statements produce output.  I see "In" but not "Out".  I closed Spyder and reopened, then rebooted, no luck.  I'm sure this is very stupid.
Thanks

```
============
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]: print("Hello world")

In [2]:
```

Comment: Perhaps Spyder is sending the output to a separate window or tab?

Comment: Or the OUT is turned off.  How or why would that happen?  So weird. And I'm guessing I am going to feel stupid when I figure it out.

Comment: Weird, it fails in Jupyter QTConsole also, the exact same failure

Comment: Some stuff does  product output                                                                       In[10]:  license
Out[10]: See https://www.python.org/psf/license/